# <span> elements inside a slider that are impossible to center?

Tags: css, html

`.nivo-controlNav` does center itself inside the slider, but i can't get to center `.nivo-controlNav span` inside `.nivo-controlNav`.

**code inspector:**

[image]

```
.nivo-controlNav {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
}
.nivo-controlNav span {
    text-align: center;
}
.nivo-controlNav a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    background: url(images/bullets.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    border: 0;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.nivo-controlNav a.active {
    background-position: 0 -22px;
}
.nivo-directionNav a {
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: url(images/arrows.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    border: 0;
}
a.nivo-nextNav {
    background-position: -30px 0;
    right: 15px;
}
a.nivo-prevNav {
    left: 15px;
}
.nivo-caption {
    text-shadow:none;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.nivo-caption a {
    color:#efe9d1;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.shadow-top {
    height: 10px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#111), to(#333));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#111, #333);
    -pie-background: linear-gradient(#111, #333);
}
.shadow-bottom {
    height: 10px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#333), to(#111));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#333, #111);
    -pie-background: linear-gradient(#333, #111);
}
.shadow-slider {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 940px;
    height: 10px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#999), to(#FFF));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#999, #DDD);
    -pie-background: linear-gradient(#222, #000);
}
#slider img {
    float: left;
    width: 958px;
    height: 458px;
}
```

**EDIT:**
(I managed to center the div, but now `.nivo-controlNav a` loses its width and height because is not floating left).

How to solve this?

```
#slider-wrapper {
    float: left;
    height: 500px;
}
#slider {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    position:relative;
    background:url(images/loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
#slider img {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    display: none;
}
.nivo-controlNav {
    margin: 480px auto 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
}
.nivo-controlNav span {

}
.nivo-controlNav a {
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    background: url(images/bullets.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    border: 0;
    margin-right: 3px;
}
.nivo-controlNav a.active {
    background-position: 0 -22px;
}
.nivo-directionNav a {
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: url(images/arrows.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    border: 0;
}
a.nivo-nextNav {
    background-position: -30px 0;
    right: 15px;
}
a.nivo-prevNav {
    left: 15px;
}
.nivo-caption {
    text-shadow:none;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.nivo-caption a {
    color:#efe9d1;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve that by just using:

```
.nivo-controlNav span {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I would also remove the `float:left` from the link as that can cause problems. You do need `display:block` on the link in order to be able to give it a width.

Comment: Support in older versions of FF is limited, requiring you to use "display: -moz-inline-stack;" as well.  IE7 also only has limited support for the inline-block option.  Modern browsers should all support it fairly well though.

Answer (score 0):

You have a CSS class for `.nivo-controlNav a` set to `float: left;` which is likely overriding your `text-align: center` on the class `.nivo-controlNav span`

EDIT: To accomplish what you're after, try replacing your **span** elements with one parent **ul** and an **li** element where you have the spans now. Then add the following to your CSS and continue using float: left on your a elements.

```
.nivo-controlNav li {
   text-align: center;
   list-style: none;
}
```

Let me know if this isn't clear and I'll try to setup an example.

Comment: If you check the computed styles for your anchor tag, I think you'll find that it's being treated as an inline element which will not apply a set width or height.  You likely want to be applying your width and height to the enclosing span and setting the span to display:block

Comment: if the span elements is set to block then links are no longer stacked horizontally.

Comment: @janoChen I think I'm getting the picture of what you're trying to do now. See my edit in my answer.